# Servet and JSP tag have different results from request.getRequestURI()

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I use Spring MVC for a web site. I need to access a JSP page with the following url

http://127.0.0.1/passwordReset

In the controller for this page, HttpServletRequest request.getRequestURI() produces the following:

```
/passwordReset
```

On the page, a custom JSP tag is included the following way:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/myTag.jsp" />
```

This tag extends SimpleTagSupport. In the doTag method, I have the following code

```
    JspContext context = getJspContext();       
    PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();  
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest(); 
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
```

and the output is

```
/WEB-INF/views/passwordReset.jsp
```

Why is there this difference? How can I get "/passwordReset" from the custom tag?

Comment: Is this the same request object? If they are different requests then why  they would have the same URI? Or why would the servlet doesn't have a history of requests?

Comment: They are involved in the same web request which invokes the servlet. The servlet displays the JSP page, and the custom JSP tag is part of the JSP page.

Comment: No, the servlet is *not* displays the JSP,  it forwards it to another request on the server that swallows its attributes and renders a JSP.

Comment: @RomanC: the claim *"another request"* is **not** true. It's still physically the same request. It looks like you're confusing "forwarding" with "redirecting". See abovelinked duplicate for the answer.